# Not able to copy file from DBFS to local desktop in Databricks

Tags: python, databricks

I want to save or copy my file from the dbfs to my desktop (local). I use this command but get an error:

```
dbutils.fs.cp('/dbfs/username/test.txt', 'C:\Users\username\Desktop') 
Error: SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

When I lookup the dbutils.fs.help() for my case, I followed the instructions:

```
dbutils.fs provides utilities for working with FileSystems. Most methods in this package can take either a DBFS path (e.g., "/foo" or "dbfs:/foo"), or another FileSystem URI. For more info about a method, use dbutils.fs.help("methodName"). In notebooks, you can also use the %fs shorthand to access DBFS. The %fs shorthand maps straightforwardly onto dbutils calls. For example, "%fs head --maxBytes=10000 /file/path" translates into "dbutils.fs.head("/file/path", maxBytes = 10000)".

fsutils
cp(from: String, to: String, recurse: boolean = false): boolean -> Copies a file or directory, possibly across FileSystems
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the Databricks CLI for this task.

Install the CLI on your local machine and run `databricks configure` to authenticate. Use an access token generated under user settings as the password.

Once you have the CLI installed and configured to your workspace, you can copy files to and from DBFS like this:

`databricks fs cp dbfs:/path_to_file/my_file /path_to_local_file/my_file`

You can also use the shorthand

`dbfs cp dbfs:/path_to_file /path_to_local_file`

Comment: I used pip install to add the CLI library. Then, I followed your instruction to install CLI on my local machine but that's where I fail. I am not able to setup a token inside Databricks as I am not the admin. Can you guide me what I should do next?

Comment: You don't need to install the CLI on your Databricks cluster, only on your local machine.  Unfortunately, if you aren't admin and don't have access to user settings you'll need to request an auth token from your admin.