# Unable to save file from Databricks to Desktop

Tags: python, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I installed the CLI rest api and now I want to save a test file to my local desktop. This is the command I have but it throws me a syntax error:

```
dbfs cp dbfs:/myname/test.pptx /Users/myname/Desktop. 

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    dbfs cp dbfs:/myname/test.pptx /Users/myname/Desktop
```

Note, I am on a Mac, so hopefully the path is correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a website about problem in programming. How is your question related to this topic?

Comment: Because he's trying to programmatically move a file from one place to another and getting a syntax error

Comment: Where are you running this command?  On a mac you can open up a terminal and use `pwd` to get the path to the directory you are in.  Then you can use that as the destination path, for example.

Comment: @RaphaelK I ran pwd in Databricks and it gives me:'/databricks/driver' and on my local machine I get: /Users/myname.

Comment: In your mac terminal run `dbfs ls dbfs:/myname`  What is the output?

Comment: it states invalid synthax

Comment: Hi @cocoo84hh Could you please try with debug mode and share the full stack trace on this error? cmd: "dbfs cp dbfs:/myfname/test.pptx \Users\myname\Desktop --debug"

Comment: Hi @cocoo84hh Could you please share the full stack trace on this error?

Comment: Hi @cocoo84hh Any update on this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, could you please share the full stack trace on this error?

Comment: Hi @cocoo84hh Checkout SO post which addressing how to save files from DBFS to local machine:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864457/not-able-to-copy-file-from-dbfs-to-local-desktop-in-databricks/59134141#59134141

Answer (score 0):

To download files from DBFS to local machine, you can checkout similar SO thread, which addressing similar issue:

[Not able to copy file from DBFS to local desktop in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58864457/not-able-to-copy-file-from-dbfs-to-local-desktop-in-databricks/59134141#59134141)

**OR**

Alternately, you can use GUI tool called DBFS Explorer to download the files on you local machine.

DBFS Explorer was created as a quick way to upload and download files to the Databricks filesystem (DBFS). This will work with both AWS and Azure instances of Databricks. You will need to create a bearer token in the web interface in order to connect.

**Reference:** [DBFS Explorer for Databricks](https://datathirst.net/projects/dbfs-explorer)

Hope this helps.